Do I need to show or submit any kind of marriage certificate in university or embassy if my wife and I want to study in same University?
I am a student and so is my wife, we want to apply in the same university for completing our masters programme. So can you please tell me that if we need to submit any marriage certificate to the University and in the embassy so that we can get the same university??

Is one considered to be dependent of the other? Or are you asking whether by virtue of you studying there, your wife should be entitled to preferential acceptance criteria?

If you want to know about university acceptance criteria for married couples, you need to ask the university.

It would be very surprising if the fact that you are married to another applicant would have any impact on admission to a German university. You would just be expected to both get an offer from the same university each on your own merits, and then coordinate in which offer you accept. Thus, I would expect that the universities don't require your marriage certificate, because they don't care that you are married.

The marriage certificate might matter when it comes to a visa.
